# FabricJs Can't draw with "DrawMode button"

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I want to have the possibility to draw rectangle only after clicking a button .

Javascript :

```
$("#select").click(function() {
    DrawingRectangle = false;
});
$("#draw").click(function() {
    DrawingRectangle = true;
    draw();
}); 

function draw() {
    if (DrawingRectangle == true) {
        canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o) {
            var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
            isDown = true;
            origX = pointer.x;
            origY = pointer.y;

            rectangle = new fabric.Rect({
                left: origX,
                top: origY,
                fill: 'transparent',
                stroke: 'red',
                strokeWidth: 3,
            });
            canvas.add(rectangle);
        });

        canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o) {
            if (!isDown) return;
            var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
            if (origX > pointer.x) {
                rectangle.set({
                    left: Math.abs(pointer.x)
                });
            }
            if (origY > pointer.y) {
                rectangle.set({
                    top: Math.abs(pointer.y)
                });
            }

            rectangle.set({
                width: Math.abs(origX - pointer.x)
            });
            rectangle.set({
                height: Math.abs(origY - pointer.y)
            });
            canvas.renderAll();
        });

        canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o) {
            isDown = false;
            DrawingRectangle = false;
        });
    }
}
```

HTML :

```
<canvas id="paper" width="800" height="300" style="border:1px solid #ccc;position: absolute; z-index : 1"></canvas>
<li align="center"><button  id="draw">Draw ROI</button></li>
<li align="center"><button  id="select">Select ROI(s)</button></li>
```

I don't know why the code in the IF statement is never fired . 
I was thinking aout using `canvas.off` but I can't figure out, how it can work with it .

My alert don't show too so I guess DrawingRectangle is never true .

Comment: You must put the if statement in the onload event or in a function that you call from a click event or other.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette All the code is in the onload event

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette my bad i confused onload and document.ready , can you give me an example of what you are saying ?

Comment: where is the code if(DrawingRectangle==true) { ... }? in document.ready? In this case it will only be called once.

Comment: Yes in document;ready then in draw function called when the button is clicked i want a button that enable/disable the possibility to draw . i tried to put outside the document.ready still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your canvas position is absolute and z-index is 1. So it comes on the top of your button. So that button was not clickable. You can use `canvas.on` and `canvas.off` to register the events. [Check](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/Working-with-events).

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('paper');
var isDown = false;
$("#select").click(function() {
    DrawingRectangle = false;
    canvas.selection = true;
    canvas.off('mouse:down');
    canvas.off('mouse:move');
    canvas.off('mouse:up');
    changeSelectableStatus(true);
});

$("#draw").click(function() {
    canvas.selection = false;
    draw();
    changeSelectableStatus(false);
});

function changeSelectableStatus(val) {
    canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
        obj.selectable = val;
    })
    canvas.renderAll();
}

function draw() {
    canvas.on('mouse:down', onMouseDown);
    canvas.on('mouse:move', onMouseMove);
    canvas.on('mouse:up', onMouseUp);
}

function onMouseDown(o) {
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    isDown = true;
    origX = pointer.x;
    origY = pointer.y;

    rectangle = new fabric.Rect({
        left: origX,
        top: origY,
        fill: 'transparent',
        stroke: 'red',
        strokeWidth: 3,
        selectable: false
    });
    canvas.add(rectangle);
}

function onMouseMove(o) {
    if (!isDown) return;
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    if (origX > pointer.x) {
        rectangle.set({
            left: Math.abs(pointer.x)
        });
    }
    if (origY > pointer.y) {
        rectangle.set({
            top: Math.abs(pointer.y)
        });
    }

    rectangle.set({
        width: Math.abs(origX - pointer.x)
    });
    rectangle.set({
        height: Math.abs(origY - pointer.y)
    });
    canvas.renderAll();
};

function onMouseUp(o) {
    rectangle.setCoords();
    isDown = false;
    DrawingRectangle = false;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="paper" width="800" height="300" style="border:1px solid #ccc;"></canvas>
<li align="center"><button  id="draw">Draw ROI</button></li>
<li align="center"><button  id="select">Select ROI(s)</button></li>
```