# FabricJs canvas Dragging First object loaded will drag all object

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

Hi i have a fabricJs canvas and i load an image . after that i draw rectangle on it (Region of interest)

What i want is , when i drag the image to move on it (after a zoom for exemple) all the rectangle move with it .

That's my actual code .

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
fabric.Image.fromURL("/images/test.png", (oImg) => {
                canvas.add(oImg);
                canvas.sendToBack(oImg);
                canvas.renderAll();
            }, {evented: false, selectable: false, hasBorders: false, hasControls: false, hasRotatingPoint: false});
var text = new fabric.Textbox('1. Text inside canvas', { 
  left: 100, 
  top: 50,
  width:300,
  fill: 'white'
});

canvas.add(text);

$("#zoomIn").click(function(){
    zoomIn();
});

$("#zoomOut").click(function(){
    zoomOut();
});

$("#btnResetZoom").click(function(){
    resetZoom();
});

function zoomIn() {
    canvas.setZoom(canvas.getZoom() *1.1);
    canvas.renderAll();
}
function zoomOut() {
    canvas.setZoom(canvas.getZoom() * 0.9);
    canvas.renderAll();        
}
function resetZoom() {
    canvas.setZoom(1);
    canvas.renderAll();


}


 var DrawingRectangle;

            var rectangle, isDown, origX, origY;
   $("#select").click(function(){
    canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
      canvas.forEachObject(function(object){ 
    object.selectable = true; 
       object.evented =true;
})

    });
    $("#draw").click(function(){
        DrawingRectangle = true;
        canvas.forEachObject(function(object){ 
        object.selectable = false; 
        object.evented =false;
})
        draw();

    });
    $("#delete").click(function(){
        canvas.isDrawingMode = false;

    });
    function draw(){        
            canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o){
                var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
                isDown = true;
                origX = pointer.x;
                origY = pointer.y;

                rectangle = new fabric.Rect({
                    left: origX,
                    top: origY,
                    fill: 'transparent',
                    stroke: 'red',
                    strokeWidth: 3,
                    selectable: true,
                });
                rectangle.hasRotatingPoint=true;
                canvas.add(rectangle);
            });

            canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o){
                if (!isDown) return;
                var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
                if(origX>pointer.x){
                    rectangle.set({ left: Math.abs(pointer.x) });
                }
                if(origY>pointer.y){
                    rectangle.set({ top: Math.abs(pointer.y) });
                }

                rectangle.set({ width: Math.abs(origX - pointer.x) });
                rectangle.set({ height: Math.abs(origY - pointer.y) });
                canvas.renderAll();
            });

            canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o){
                isDown = false;
                canvas.off('mouse:down');
                canvas.off('mouse:move');
                canvas.off('mouse:up');

            });
    }
```

What i do actually is when i click on the "Draw" button all my object become unselectable so i can draw over the image. 
Then when i click on the "select" button , all my object become selectable (that only work for my image but not for the rectangles that i draw)
and once i move my image , the image come in foreground and my rectangle diseappear in the background.

1) Why my rectangle can't be selectable
2) How can i move all object when the image object (i guess with ID 0 because it's the first loaded object) is moved .

> EDIT : Solved No1 . still have issue with No 2 .
>    i Tried to fire event with my image object but doesn't work . like this :
>
> ```
>   oImg.on('mouse:down', function(o){ it says it's undefined
> ```

Comment: Here I have given an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46955475/3551786). Have you checked?

Comment: @Durga that doesn' help me for selecting all object .

Comment: That will work for all object.

Comment: @Durga  still looking at the answere i don't see how it can help me with my current problem , i  edited my post , take a look

Comment: you want that image also draggable ? or you want thar as background?

Comment: Draggable ,when i drag the image i want all rectangle follow the image .

Comment: @Durga tell me if you need more informations

Comment: Clarify me, you want 1) botton>draw ractangle, where you draw rectangles.2)selectable> select objects(move,rotate).3)zoom in/out button. 4)and in canvas one image will there, if you drag that image what ever rectangles there they will drag with that much distance with which image covered .

Comment: @Durga 1/2/3 is almost done , i just need 4  , When dragging the image , the rectangle will be dragged with the image .

Comment: @Durga  is that enough clear for u ?

Comment: Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/durga598/ufnx0833/), i will update it for image move later.

Comment: @Durga that's what i actually have, now referring on your fiddle  edit the grey background and replace it with an image , and make it draggable with the ROIs

Comment: @Durga  Thanks for your awesome help

Comment: @Durga Did you update the fiddle or not yet ?

Comment: check updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/durga598/ufnx0833/1/)

Comment: @Durga It works but my image once selected is going foreground , how can i avoid this ? i want the image is staying behind the rectangle .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('paper',{preserveObjectStacking:true});
canvas.backgroundColor = 'grey';
var isDown = false;
fabric.Image.fromURL("https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.svg?v=6e4af45f4d66", function (oImg) {
    canvas.add(oImg);
    canvas.sendToBack(oImg);
    oImg.on('mousedown', function() {
        oImg.centerPt = this.getCenterPoint();
        canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
            obj.origPose = new fabric.Point(obj.left, obj.top);
        })
    })
    oImg.on('mouseup', function() {
        delete this.centerPt;
        canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
            delete obj.origPose;
        })
    })
    oImg.on('moving', function(evt) {
        var self = this;
        var diff = this.getCenterPoint().subtract(self.centerPt);
        canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
            if (obj == self) return;
            obj.set({
                left: obj.origPose.x + diff.x,
                top: obj.origPose.y + diff.y
            })
            obj.setCoords();
        })
    })
    canvas.renderAll();
}, {
    selectable: false,
});
var text = new fabric.Textbox('1. Text inside canvas', {
    left: 100,
    top: 50,
    width: 300,
    fill: 'white',
    selectable: false
});

canvas.add(text);
$("#zoomIn").click(function() {
    zoomIn();
});

$("#zoomOut").click(function() {
    zoomOut();
});

$("#btnResetZoom").click(function() {
    resetZoom();
});

function zoomIn() {
    canvas.setZoom(canvas.getZoom() * 1.1);
    canvas.renderAll();
}

function zoomOut() {
    canvas.setZoom(canvas.getZoom() * 0.9);
    canvas.renderAll();
}

function resetZoom() {
    canvas.setZoom(1);
    canvas.renderAll();
}
$("#select").click(function() {
    DrawingRectangle = false;
    canvas.selection = true;
    canvas.off('mouse:down');
    canvas.off('mouse:move');
    canvas.off('mouse:up');
    changeSelectableStatus(true);
});

$("#draw").click(function() {
    canvas.selection = false;
    draw();
    changeSelectableStatus(false);
});

function changeSelectableStatus(val) {
    canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
        obj.selectable = val;
    })
    canvas.renderAll();
}

function draw() {
    canvas.on('mouse:down', onMouseDown);
    canvas.on('mouse:move', onMouseMove);
    canvas.on('mouse:up', onMouseUp);
}

function onMouseDown(o) {
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    isDown = true;
    origX = pointer.x;
    origY = pointer.y;

    rectangle = new fabric.Rect({
        left: origX,
        top: origY,
        fill: 'transparent',
        stroke: 'red',
        strokeWidth: 3,
        selectable: false
    });
    canvas.add(rectangle);
}

function onMouseMove(o) {
    if (!isDown) return;
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    if (origX > pointer.x) {
        rectangle.set({
            left: Math.abs(pointer.x)
        });
    }
    if (origY > pointer.y) {
        rectangle.set({
            top: Math.abs(pointer.y)
        });
    }

    rectangle.set({
        width: Math.abs(origX - pointer.x)
    });
    rectangle.set({
        height: Math.abs(origY - pointer.y)
    });
    canvas.renderAll();
};

function onMouseUp(o) {
    rectangle.setCoords();
    isDown = false;
    DrawingRectangle = false;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="paper" width="800" height="300" style="border:1px solid #ccc;"></canvas>
<button  id="draw">Draw ROI</button>
<button  id="select">Select ROI(s)</button>
<button  id="zoomIn">Zoom In</button>
<button  id="zoomOut">Zoom Out</button>
<button  id="btnResetZoom">Reset Zoom</button>
```

1) Draw ROI button> draw rectangle, where you draw rectangles.

2) Select ROI button > select objects(move,rotate).

3) zoom in/out button.

4) and in canvas one image there, if you drag that image what ever objects there they will drag with that much distance with which image covered.

use `preserveObjectStacking:true` then objects wont come on top while dragging.

Comment: Add it on the image but still going in front of the rectangle while dragging   , i need to click on the canvas's background to show the rectangle again

Comment: you used this `preserveObjectStacking:true`?

Comment: Yes for the image .

Comment: No you need to add for canvas, check the snippet.

Comment: Ho sorry my bad didn't see it , it's working now Thank you !  I need help for something else in FabricJS but it's out of scope for this topic , can i msg you on twitter ?

Comment: in your previous question, I gave the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46955475/3551786) as well , dont forget to upvote.cheers ;)

Comment: Will be done but you didn't answer to my question ^^

Comment: You may. Happy to help.

Comment: i just sent  you a PM  on Twitter :)

Comment: I don't know why but with ur code , my image is moving when i'm drawing but you put object.selectable = value that is normally "false"